# Can't get recommended fix for Silverlight ContextMenu memory leaks to work

Tags: memory-leaks, silverlight-4.0, delegates, contextmenu

I am trying to create a custom `ContextMenu, S4ContextMenu`, that implements IDisposable to handle the memory leak issue, as recommended in this blog:

http://silverlight.codeplex.com/workitem/6206

I've included this code in the Dispose function of S4ContextMenu as stated in the blog:

```
MethodInfo infos = typeof(ContextMenu).GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic |  
    BindingFlags.Instance).Where(a =>     
    a.Name.Equals("HandleRootVisualMouseMove")).FirstOrDefault();

Delegate handler = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(MouseEventHandler), this , infos);
EventInfo info = Application.Current.RootVisual.GetType().GetEvent("MouseMove");
info.RemoveEventHandler(Application.Current.RootVisual, handler);
```

It compiles fine but when I run it, I get a MethodAccessException:
"`Attempt by method 'S4.Analytics.Client.Controls.S4ContextMenu.Dispose(Boolean)' to access method 'System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenu.HandleRootVisualMouseMove(System.Object, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs)' failed.`"

I've tried getting MethodInfo on `S4ContextMenu` instead of `ContextMenu` but that returns null.

I am developing in `VS 2010, targeting Silverlight 4`.

What am I missing?

How do I create this Delegate?

Although I would prefer to use this approach to deal with the memory leak issue, if someone has another way that works (and doesn't involve editing the actual `ContextMenu` or `toolkit`) that would be awesome.

Comment: So nobody else has had an issue with the Silverlight context menu??

Comment: Yeah, I'm having issues that I finally tracked down to the context menu. If I find a fix I'll let you know.

Comment: That would be awesome! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found memory leak in ContextMenu. It is in InitializeRootVisual method and occurs in Silverlight 4 and 5 the same, because there is no delete mouse event handler.

```
_rootVisual.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(HandleRootVisualMouseMove);
```

To resolve this problem, You need to rebuild Silverlight Toolkit project.

1. Download source code from https://silverlight.codeplex.com/relases
2. Open project Control.Input.Toolkit -> ContextMenu -> ContextMenu.cs and replace InitializeRootVisual method by following code:

-

```
private void InitializeRootVisual()
{
    if (null == _rootVisual)
    {
        // Try to capture the Application's RootVisual
        _rootVisual = Application.Current.RootVisual as FrameworkElement;
        if (null != _rootVisual)
        {
            //Repaired by Jacek Gzel
            // Ideally, this would use AddHandler(MouseMoveEvent), but MouseMoveEvent doesn't exist
            //_rootVisual.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(HandleRootVisualMouseMove);

            var rootVisual = _rootVisual;

            // Use a weak event listener.
            var rootVisualMouseMoveListener = new WeakEventListener<ContextMenu, object, MouseEventArgs>(this);
            rootVisualMouseMoveListener.OnEventAction = (instance, source, eventArgs) => instance.HandleRootVisualMouseMove(source, eventArgs);
            rootVisualMouseMoveListener.OnDetachAction = (weakEventListener) => rootVisual.MouseMove -= weakEventListener.OnEvent;
            rootVisual.MouseMove += rootVisualMouseMoveListener.OnEvent;
        }
    }
}
```

3. Replace Toolkit DLL references in your Silverlight app.